# MySQL - How to create a child record under table2 whenever table1 is having a new record using MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

Trigger actually. But how do i make this in mysql-workbench. So that anytime i have any new records in `table1` it creates a new record referencing `table1.id` to `table2.parentid` ?

[image]

```
--- [OK] --- This is created
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`table1` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB

--- [FAIL] --- #1005 - Can't create table 'test.table2' (errno: 150)
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`table2` (
  `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `parentid` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `table1_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_table2_table1` (`parentid` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_table2_table1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`parentid` )
    REFERENCES `test`.`table1` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

**Follow up:**

1) Mysql workbench do not offer that

2) Click the table1 > click the triggers tab bottom > write

```
-- trigger module initiate
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER triggertest1 BEFORE INSERT ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table2 SET parentid = NEW.id; 
  END;
$$
DELIMITER ; --- return to normal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you have different datatype of id column in your child table change it to BIGINT(20)

Comment: Why in my trigger i have always `NEW.id` ==0 ? table2.parentid always showing 0.

Comment: The reason is very simple your trigger fires before the insertion in parent table so it wont find any id since the data has not been inserted. Change your trigger to AFTER INSERT ON